# Is it possible to set column families for transactions?

Tags: rocksdb

I need to read and update data in different Column Families in single transaction(RocksDB). Is it possible to set column families for transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes - just use the appropriate methods that take in the column family as an input https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/main/include/rocksdb/utilities/transaction.h#L455